# Problem in Creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure but it throws an error.
Can anybody tell me if there is something i am doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (ID int)
INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT 1
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (ID int)
INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT 2

CREATE PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)
AS 
BEGIN
 IF @source = 1 
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID
END
```

> ERROR:There is already an object named
>   '#tmpID' in the database.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, how do you explain that error at compile time though? I'm pretty sure it's because it is a syntax error to do `SELECT ID INTO #tmpID FROM tbl1` and not because the object already exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the T-SQL compiler gets confused, and doesn't realise that only one side of an IF would be followed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)
AS 
BEGIN
 CREATE TABLE #tmpID(ID int)
 IF @source = 1 
 INSERT INTO #tmpID SELECT ID FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 INSERT INTO #tmpID SELECT ID  FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID
END
```

Comment: Not a day goes by without learning something new. +10 if I could but I've used up my votes for today...

Comment: @Lieven - I frequently find myself trying to think like the T-SQL compiler. The trick is to say to oneself "what's the stupidest thing I could do here?"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a temporary table. This should be enough:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT) 
AS  
BEGIN 
 IF @source = 1
    SELECT ID FROM tbl1  
 ELSE 
    SELECT ID  FROM tbl2  
END
```

Answer (score -2):

There already exists a temporary table #tmpID in your database. Try using this before your procedure.

```
Drop table #tmpID
```